# NavigationPage with iOS PrefersLargeTitles snaps title when scrolling

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I tried to get the same large title behavior like the settings app on iOS when the user scrolls down. The transition between the large title and the small title is smooth. But on Xamarin Forms the header snaps.

In my NavigationPage i set `PrefersLargeTitles="true"`. In the embedded content page i set `LargeTitleDisplay="Always"` and `UseSafeArea="true"`. The content in the page looks like this:

```xml
<ContentPage.Content>
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <ListView />
        <Frame x:Name="LoadingFrame" /> <!-- Only visible until ListView is loaded -->
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

I tried setting `NavigationPage.IsNavigationBarTranslucent="True"`. Then it works, but only if i disable SafeArea (`Page.UseSafeArea="False"`) in the ContentPage. Disabling SafeArea is not what i want, because now the content is behind the notch.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

The trick was to change top constraint of list to **superView** instead of **safe area** which **only works on Native**.

```
extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true;
```

On **Xamarin.Forms**, I tried these solutions:

1. Use a **custom renderer** to set the LayoutConstraints of the scrollable view (**Doesn't work**)
2. Create a UITableViewController in a custom renderer then convert the Xamarin TableView element to a UITableView and set it to the TableView property of the UITableViewController then PushViewController to the new UITableViewController. (**work**)

You can raise the problem on github for better support：

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Comment: Hi @MorganLi_MSFT , thank you. I also tried setting LayoutConstraints via custom renderer and setting some other properties from answers here at SO. But nothing works. I don't understand your second solution. XF ListView is already a iOS UITableView and what is a PushViewController? XF Support via github looks dead. :-(The team is only active on MAUI.

Comment: You could refer to [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service)  Create a new TableViewController by platform API and set its property as the context mentioned. (This way may cause many works so it‘s not recommended)
By the way, Xamarin Team still maintains Github yet.